# Return objects in list that the first name starts with a certain value

Tags: json, jmespath

I am trying to filter through this list of objects and only return the objects where the firstName starts with a specific value.

```json
[
  {"firstName":"Paul","lastName":"Collins"},
  {"firstName":"Jerry","lastName":"Johnson"},
  {"firstName":"Jody","lastName":"Johnson","occupation":"Occupado","company":"Companio"},
  {"firstName":"Paul","lastName":"Johanson","occupation":"Developer","company":"Developer Co"}
]
```

The farthest I've gotten is this:

```
([].firstName | [?starts_with(@,'J') == `true`])
```

Which returns:

```json
[
  "Jerry",
  "Jody"
]
```

However, I want to return whole objects that fit this condition, not just the firstName field. My desired output would be:

```json
[
  {"firstName":"Jerry","lastName":"Johnson"},
  {"firstName":"Jody","lastName":"Johnson","occupation":"Occupado","company":"Companio"},
]
```

I couldn't find a way to pass an array of strings to `starts_with`. I could get the values from the return and interpolate them into multiple queries one query with a bunch of `"|| firstName == name1 || firstName == name2"`. However I am wanting to try to do this in one query string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mind that jq and JMESPath are two totally different beasts. Which one are you looking to use?

Comment: I could use either. I wasn't sure if it was possible in jmespath and therefore was open to suggestions in jq. Now that it is answered I will remove the jq tag

Comment: Well, now you have an issue because you have two different but valid answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JMESPath, if that's what you are looking for, the [filter projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections) can be applied on any property of an array, by simply specifying the said properties in the brackets  selecting the array itself.

So, rather than going `[].firstName`, the property comes inside the brackets, e.g. `[?firstName == 'Jerry']`, would give you the whole object of the person named *Jerry*.

Then you can apply this using `start_with()`:

```
[?starts_with(firstName,'J')]
```

Which will yield the expected

```json
[
  {
    "firstName": "Jerry",
    "lastName": "Johnson"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Jody",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "occupation": "Occupado",
    "company": "Companio"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `select( ... )` to filter a stream. By extension, you can use `map( select( ... ) )` to remove items from an array.

```
map( select( .firstName | startswith("J") ) )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xXXQMJrtpl)